Spring cloud gateway Response header not set when sending back response
I have declared two custom Global filter in spring cloud gateway application. Iam setting response header in both filters.
The error Iam encountering is

Blockquote

"Error [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException] for HTTP GET "/location", but ServerHttpResponse already committed"
Filter definition are below:
@Component
public class CustomRequestFilter1 implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        System.out.println("inside CustomRequestFilter1 class filter method:");
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        request.mutate().header("globalFilterRequestKey", "globalFilterRequestKey");
        return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable( () -> {
            System.out.println("CustomRequestFilter1 response");
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.getHeaders().set("header1", "CustomRequestFilter1");
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -1;
    }
}

@Component
public class CustomRequestFilter2 implements GlobalFilter, Ordered  {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        System.out.println("inside CustomRequestFilter2 class filter method:");
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        request.mutate().header("globalFilterRequestKey2", "globalFilterRequestKey2");
        return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.fromRunnable( () -> {
            System.out.println("CustomRequestFilter2 response");
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.getHeaders().set("header1", "CustomRequestFilter2");
        }));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}

